# Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <html> of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

i am trying to get json from server and place it into my RecyclerView, but its says "java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject". I am try to track my json, but its shown nothing. Whats wrong, how can i solve this?

```
 public class AsyncLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    Context ctx;
    `enter code here`ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private static final String TAG = "AsyncLoaderTask";
String json_url="http://stocksearchapi.com/api/
api_key=43c30be222eb8b48f8d562f23b00e189bc42b0e9&search_text=CSO";
public AsyncLoaderTask(Context ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    progressDialog= new ProgressDialog(ctx);
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait..");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Download in Progress");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();

}



@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        try {
             URL url = new URL(json_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection =(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                stringBuilder.append(line+"\n");
                Thread.sleep(500);

            }
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();



            String json_data= stringBuilder.toString().trim();

            JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(json_data);

            JSONArray jsonArray =jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
            DatabaseHandler databaseHandler=new DatabaseHandler(ctx);
            SQLiteDatabase db= databaseHandler.getWritableDatabase();

            int count =0;
            while (count<jsonArray.length())
            {

                JSONObject JO=jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
                count++;
                databaseHandler.putInformation(JO.getString("company_name"),JO.getString("company_symbol"),db);


            }


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }


    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: what's the content of your `json_data`?

Answer (score 0):

**NEW**

```
 response = [{"company_name": "Amazon.com, Inc.", "company_symbol": "AMZN", "listing_exchange": "NASDAQ"}]
```

If this the response, then do like this

```
 JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray(response);
 JsonObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

 //do with this object now
```

**OLD**

Return a String in doInBackground()

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    Log.i(TAG, "do in background");

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(params[0]);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

        // 200 represents HTTP OK
        if (statusCode == 201 || statusCode == 200) {

            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
            }
            ourresult = response.toString();
            return ourresult;
        }
        else if (statusCode == 400 || statusCode == 401 || statusCode == 404) {

            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("Response",2);
            ourresult=jsonObject.toString();
        }
        else if(statusCode == 500)
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("Response",3);
            ourresult=jsonObject.toString();
        }
        else
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("Response",4);
            ourresult=jsonObject.toString();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e("Get", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return ourresult; 
}
```

And Encode a JsonObject using String

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    JSONObject json;
    try {
        json = new JSONObject(result);

        //Handle Response 2,3,4 if any
        ..........
        //else
        JSONArray jsonArray =json.getJSONArray("server_response");
        DatabaseHandler databaseHandler=new DatabaseHandler(ctx);
        SQLiteDatabase db= databaseHandler.getWritableDatabase();

       do your stuff here...

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Still the same error : Value <html> of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

The JSON data that i want to fetch is like this [{"company_name": "Amazon.com, Inc.", "company_symbol": "AMZN", "listing_exchange": "NASDAQ"}]